# Eclipse: I have added the JAR file. java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Eclipse, I have added the JAR file under `lib->mysql-connector...jar`, but I am still getting the error that the class is not found.

I have read many other posts related to the same problem, and they point to adding the JAR file, but I have already done this step.

Thanks for the help.

**Error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:171)
    at TTDB.TT_DoQuery(TTDB.java:65)
    at TTDB.TT_Insert(TTDB.java:58)
    at TTDB.main(TTDB.java:109)
```

**Code:**

```
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jbc.Driver");
        // Connect to the database
        connect = DriverManager.getConnection(address);

        statement = connect.createStatement();
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);

    }
    catch (Exception e){
        throw e;
    } finally {
        TT_Close();
    }
```

**Screenshots*

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a `d`.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

Note that JDBC 4 compliant `Driver` implementations don't need to be explicitly loaded with `Class.forName(String)`. The `Driver` is registered through classpath scanning. Find out if your library is JDBC 4 compliant and remove the call to `Class.forName(String)` if it is.

Comment: Please check the question OP has aleady mentioned that thing

Comment: @BhavikAmbani What did I miss?

Comment: How would I load the driver now? Would I just add it as an import?

Comment: When I remove Class.forName I get the error `No suitable driver found for jbdc:mysql://localhost/test_schema?user=root&password=root`

Comment: @AustinTruong With JDBC 4, just the fact of having the class on your classpath will register it.

Comment: @AustinTruong Ah, it might not be JDBC 4 then.